# JS - setAttribute() doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
            <form id="register-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter user name" />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dof">Date of Birth</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dof" onchange="return enableSave(event);" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
              </div>

              <button id="save-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="save(event);">Save</button>
            </form>


<script type="text/javascript">

var savebutton = document.getElementById('save-button');
savebutton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

function enableSave() {
    var n = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var d = document.getElementById('dof').value;
    if(n && d) {
        savebutton.setAttribute('enabled', 'enabled');
    }
};

</script>
```

My function enableSave() does not set attribute of SAVE button into 'enabled'.

I do not understand why.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Your code sets `enabled` attribute (if correctly timed), but it's not a standard attribute, hence setting it has no effect. To "enable" a button, remove `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Or set `savebutton.disabled = false;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `return` from `onchange=return enableSave(event);` and instead of `savebutton.setAttribute('enabled', 'enabled');` use `savebutton.removeAttribute('disabled');`

UPDATE: 
Here is a working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/KJRrUVynV378XbpzcRzd?p=preview)